# R: Find values of previous/next rows of group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with orders. And I want to calculate intervals between orders for each customer.
So, dataset looks like:

```
N   order_id  user_id  order_date
1:  1         1        2016-11-18
2:  2         2        2016-11-20
3:  3         3        2016-11-21
4:  4         1        2016-11-22
5:  5         2        2016-11-23
```

What I need is to find a column *previous_order_date* which will show the date of a previous order for current customer. So my data.table will look like this:

```
N   order_id  user_id  order_date  previous_order_date
1:  1         1        2016-11-18  NA
2:  2         2        2016-11-20  NA
3:  3         3        2016-11-21  NA
4:  4         1        2016-11-22  2016-11-18
5:  5         2        2016-11-23  2016-11-20
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `shift`: `dt[, past_date:=shift(order_date), by=user_id]`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.
PS. I had old version of data.table, *shift()* only works from 1.9.5